# Unable to print last line using awk after using trap in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, bash-trap

Bash file is as

```
#!/bin/bash



SomeErrorHandler () {
    (( errcount += $? ))

 echo -e $errcount


}

trap SomeErrorHandler ERR


uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null

uname -a 1>/dev/null

declare -a f
         # this is never printed

f="$(SomeErrorHandler)"

echo -e "$f" | awk 'END {print}'
```

I want the returning value be from the value of `a` as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

to return the last match which is `5` instead the output just echos everything in `a`.

I also tried with `sed` but output is same. It seems that this is just one record

Comment: I doubt if it's your problem (I can't figure out what it is you're really trying to do) but `awk 'END {print}'` is undefined behavior per POSIX. It'll either print the value of the last line read or print a null string or do something/anything else. Use `awk '{rec=$0} END{print rec}'` for portability if you're trying to use awk to mimic `tail -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that all the `echo`es from `SomeErrorHandler()` are stored in variable `f`?
This is not happening.

```
SomeErrorHandler () {
   if (( $# > 0 )); then
      echo -e $errcount
   else
      (( errcount += $? ))
   fi
}

trap SomeErrorHandler ERR
errcount=0

uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null
uname +a 2>/dev/null

uname -a 1>/dev/null

# Use a random parameter for displaying the current value
SomeErrorHandler show
```